# IE Automation with Windows PowerShell

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, automation, scripting

I want to ask about manipulating IE via Powershell.
My goal is to write script that will automatically perform some actions in the browser (on the client side – navigate to  page, perform actions, measure time between responses, etc.)

I have this little thing:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate("http://google.com")
```

Now I want to check whether the browser stopped page rendering (assuming, that google takes like 30 seconds to load).
As I checked with `$ie | get-member` there is DocumentCompleted property (event), but I don’t know how to access/compare it.
How should I do that?

Or maybe I should use .NET instead COM object and initiate `$ie` with `[system.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser]` ?

cheers

edit:
Well... `$ie.busy` works, but (what maybe I haven't made clear earlier) I want to know exact moment of the page rendering competition. Checking `$ie.busy` in infinite loop every second might work but I suppose it's not the best way to do that.

Let's say page is loading some time (rendering is long due to the gigantic scripts on client side). I would like how long does it take to:

1. load page
2. how long it will take to reload/re-render after changing some data and clicking 'Save'.

Comment: any solution with full source code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check .busy property.

edit:

Status property will also work here. However you can use tool like Firebug to see page load time.

Comment: For now I will stick with .busy, although PS Even Library proposed by Jason is something worth look into. Firebug is not the case, as I want to load page about 1000 times and see the average load time.

Answer (score 1):

If you do decide to go .NET instead of PowerShell, [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) is great for this.  It will give you tons of flexibility over the WebBrowser control and is a lot easier to use. You can also drive Firefox now in version 2.

Comment: You will have to use Powershell V2 with WatiN, as WatiN needs STA

Comment: Later (just for fun) I used WatiN with C# and it was great. Thanks for that hint!

Answer (score 0):

Since it has an event, you could try out the [PowerShell Eventing Library](http://www.codeplex.com/PSEventing).  It says that it supports COM events, though I haven't tried it.